# Updated Google Chrome changed absolute positioning XHTML 1.0

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Some of the computers in the office has already updated their Google Chrome Browsers.  I am currently on Version 38.0.2125.111 m.  The website we have was built with XHTML 1.0.  I haven't made any changes to the website, but all of a sudden the left positioning I have set at 800px is now more left than it should be.

I know it was the update to Google Chrome, because not everybody has this issue with outdated versions. I also checked it on Chrome Canary and it does the same thing.  I cross checked the website with IE 10 and it seems to render it just fine.  Right now I have some text that is overlapping with another DIV (search box).  Here is the problem part.  I could just add more left PX, but I wanted to know why it changed and maybe what would be better way so this doesn't happen again.

```
<div style="left: 800px; height: 30px; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -11px;
        z-index: 1;">
        <a id="HyperLink1" href="#" style="color:Yellow;font-style:italic;">Logout</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Google Chrome has changed the way of positioning, but to avoid it and other futures modifications, I suggest you to use [a CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/), which assure you you'll have 'standart' initial CSS properties on every browsers.